# Adjust DataTables ordering

Tags: sorting, datatables

I have the following data I'm passing to a DataTables table:

```js
data = [{'state': 'Baseline', 'contact': 'Johnny', 'years_active': 10},
        {'state': '1', 'contact': 'Rachel', 'years_active': 10},
        {'state': '2', 'contact': 'Steve', 'years_active': 8}]
```

The table has three columns: `state`, `contact`, and `years_active`. When I sort on the `state` column, the row with `state='Baseline'` is at the bottom of the table. Is there any way to adjust the sorting mechanism so this row will be on top?

Maybe convert `Baseline` to `'0'` in the background or maybe define character values as less then number values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control the sort value in the columns [**`render`**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) callback. The `type` argument defines what scope the returned value will be used for, i.e filter, sort, display. With the magic of the `||` operator you can return -1 when the column is about to be sorted, and the value is not a number :

```js
columns: [
  { data: 'state',
    render: function(data, type) {
      if (type == 'sort') {
        return parseInt(data) || -1
      }
      return data
    }
  },
  { data: 'contact' },
  { data: 'years_active' }
]
```

see demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/721hdxa5/**